# SpatRaster Plots empty Map

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

Why does Map1 plot and Map 2 not plot?

```
Map2<-rast("C:/filepath.tif")
Map2

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 2858, 7229, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.015485, 0.015485  (x, y)
#extent      : -167.5965, -55.65545, 27.15188, 71.40801  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : Predicted_ssp245_2041_2070_brt_HighContribution_NoEXT_Map.tif 
#name        :      lyr.1 
#min value   : 0.04727112 
#max value   : 0.06187772 

plot(Map2)
```

[image: Empty map]

```
Map1<-rast("C:/filepath.tif")

Map1
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 2858, 7229, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.015485, 0.015485  (x, y)
#extent      : -167.5965, -55.65545, 27.15188, 71.40801  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : Model_Evaluation_ssp245_2041_2070_brt_HighContribution_NoEXT_Map.tif 
#name        :      lyr.1 
#min value   : 0.04712632 
#max value   : 0.06298273 

plot(Map1)
```

[image]

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: What happens if you restart R?

Comment: Perhaps mist cells are NA in the first one? Can you share the file?

Comment: R starting R does not solve the issue. Reinstalling R and R studio does not solve the issue.

Comment: @Robert Hijmans I am happy to share the file what is the best way to get it to you?

Comment: share via e.g. google drive in your post if possible, otherwise email

Comment: @Robert Hijmans I emailed them to you. Thank you

Comment: I moved the files into a different folder and it solved the problem. They plot. Maybe Arc GIS pro made hidden files in that folder that confuses R.  I don't know. Thank you again for the help.